# Setting up SSL certificate on Openfire server

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, openfire

I am trying to set up SSL certificates for Openfire XMPP server.

I deleted `keystore` file from `/etc/openfire/security/` folder and have done all SSL cert setup procedures using web interface:

- Generated CSR file from web interface
- Placed this files contents on Comodo's website
- Got CA keychain
- Placed it's contents on web interface

This was all successful - the web interface shows success message

> SSL successfully installed on Openfire server.

However I can't see any keystore file.  Will this cause me any problems?

Comment: If you can use secure ports correctly, for admin and client connexion, you can be sure that it is OK